# Python isn't registering the new module from pip install

Tags: python, windows, installation

I recently installed the requests library for python. And python does not see it, however it is installed
Console output:

```
C:\Users\Raitis\Desktop>pip3 install requests
Requirement already satisfied: requests in c:\users\raitis\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages (2.23.0)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3!=1.25.0,!=1.25.1,<1.26,>=1.21.1 in c:\users\raitis\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages (from requests) (1.25.8)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in c:\users\raitis\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages (from requests) (2019.11.28)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<3,>=2.5 in c:\users\raitis\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages (from requests) (2.9)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<4,>=3.0.2 in c:\users\raitis\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages (from requests) (3.0.4)

C:\Users\Raitis\Desktop>py
Python 3.8.0 (tags/v3.8.0:fa919fd, Oct 14 2019, 19:21:23) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import requests
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'
```

It is installed indeed, and we can see that in direcory(Screenshot:https://prnt.sc/r90uhr) and python's path is added to the enviroment PATH(Screenshot: https://prnt.sc/r90rus)

Comment: have you activate the environment or it's in global?

Comment: Don't really know what do you mean. It is in here: https://prnt.sc/r90zmd

Comment: `pip3` belongs to `pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7`, so python 3.7 and `py` starts `Python 3.8.0`, so you have multiple python versions installed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try installing the **request** library using this command instead

```
py -m pip install requests
```

Or in your case use,

```
py -m pip3 install requests
```

Comment: BTW the reason that it occurred is coz the pip3 you have globally referred to, was not referring to the same py (python.exe) file. I guess you have 2 different installations of Python environments and it's working for the other one instead (Like maybe anaconda). 

It's better to use a single environment to avoid such confusion.

Comment: Yea, I have python 3.7 and 2.7. Haven't thought about that, thanks :D